# Selenium chromedriver handle TimeoutException

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have two issues :

1. My first problem is that even when I set pageLoadTimeout to infinite a timeout exception will be raised after 300 seconds & I figured this a some kind of web socket timeout between chromedriver & the browser . How to avoid this timeout ?
2. How to handle TimeoutException ? I tried setting pageLoadTimeout to 280 seconds < 300 (web socket timeout) but when the exception raised and caught the browser becomes not responding I can't navigate nor close the window

I'm using chromedriver 2.14 latest & selenium java 2.44.0

Is this hang behavior after timeout common between different drivers ?

```
private boolean loadPage(String url) {
    try {
        Logger.getLogger(TAG).log(Level.INFO, "{0} loadPage url =  {1}", new Object[]{TAG, url});
        this.driver.getDriver().get(url);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

when TimeoutException is caught the browser becomes not responding

Comment: Have you tried explicit wait?

Comment: No i'll try it now & report back maybe the web socket session will not hang because explicit wait keeps polling ?

Comment: please try explicit wait then see effect.

Comment: sorry, can you explain in detail? I did not get your comment.

Comment: webdriver.get()  blocks until it completes,  I don't think there is any use of explicit wait after it, because the exception will already be raised

Comment: You're confused.  There is definitely an explicit wait, as Helping Hands has mentioned.  Essentially - it's a kind of Spin-Lock where it keeps retrying until a set amount of time has elapsed.  I suggest you look into ExpectedConditions - You can view the actual source of these helpers to get a better feel of how it's constructed.  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: I'm loading the page not performing a click or getting an element ! 
There is not such thing as ExpectedCondition.unitPageLoaded that load the page . Selenium provide a similar but separate timeout from page load